# Link Error while creatiing wxSashLayoutWindow in wxwidgets

Tags: c++, visual-c++, wxwidgets

I am Working on wxsashlayoutwindow but i am not able to execute ,some one please help me out of this

these are the link errors i am getting:

```
1>MyFrame.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: bool __thiscall 

wxLayoutAlgorithm::LayoutFrame(class wxFrame *,class wxWindow *)" (?

LayoutFrame@wxLayoutAlgorithm@@QAE_NPAVwxFrame@@PAVwxWindow@@@Z) referenced in function

"public: __thiscall MyFrame::MyFrame(class wxWindow *,int,class wxString const &,class 

wxPoint const &,class wxSize const &,long,class wxString const &)" (??

0MyFrame@@QAE@PAVwxWindow@@HABVwxString@@ABVwxPoint@@ABVwxSize@@J1@Z)


1>MyFrame.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall

wxSashWindow::SetSashVisible(enum wxSashEdgePosition,bool)" (?

SetSashVisible@wxSashWindow@@QAEXW4wxSashEdgePosition@@_N@Z) referenced in function 

"public: __thiscall MyFrame::MyFrame(class wxWindow *,int,class wxString const &,class 

wxPoint const &,class wxSize const &,long,class wxString const &)" (??

0MyFrame@@QAE@PAVwxWindow@@HABVwxString@@ABVwxPoint@@ABVwxSize@@J1@Z)


1>MyFrame.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: bool __thiscall 

wxSashLayoutWindow::Create(class wxWindow *,int,class wxPoint const &,class wxSize const 

&,long,class wxString const &)" (?

Create@wxSashLayoutWindow@@QAE_NPAVwxWindow@@HABVwxPoint@@ABVwxSize@@JABVwxString@@@Z) 

referenced in function "public: __thiscall MyFrame::MyFrame(class wxWindow *,int,class 

wxString const &,class wxPoint const &,class wxSize const &,long,class wxString const &)" 

(??0MyFrame@@QAE@PAVwxWindow@@HABVwxString@@ABVwxPoint@@ABVwxSize@@J1@Z)


1>MyFrame.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __thiscall

 wxSashWindow::~wxSashWindow(void)" (??1wxSashWindow@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function 

__unwindfunclet$??0wxSashLayoutWindow@@QAE@XZ$0


1>MyFrame.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: void __thiscall 

wxSashLayoutWindow::Init(void)" (?Init@wxSashLayoutWindow@@AAEXXZ) referenced in function 

"public: __thiscall wxSashLayoutWindow::wxSashLayoutWindow(void)" (??

0wxSashLayoutWindow@@QAE@XZ)


1>MyFrame.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual class 

wxClassInfo * __thiscall wxSashLayoutWindow::GetClassInfo(void)const " (?

GetClassInfo@wxSashLayoutWindow@@UBEPAVwxClassInfo@@XZ)


1>MyFrame.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual struct 

wxEventTable const * __thiscall wxSashLayoutWindow::GetEventTable(void)const " (?

GetEventTable@wxSashLayoutWindow@@MBEPBUwxEventTable@@XZ)

1>MyFrame.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual class 

wxEventHashTable & __thiscall wxSashLayoutWindow::GetEventHashTable(void)const " (?

GetEventHashTable@wxSashLayoutWindow@@MBEAAVwxEventHashTable@@XZ)


1>MyFrame.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: void __thiscall 

wxSashWindow::Init(void)" (?Init@wxSashWindow@@AAEXXZ) referenced in function "public: 

__thiscall wxSashWindow::wxSashWindow(void)" (??0wxSashWindow@@QAE@XZ)

1>MyFrame.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual class 

wxClassInfo * __thiscall wxSashWindow::GetClassInfo(void)const " (?

GetClassInfo@wxSashWindow@@UBEPAVwxClassInfo@@XZ)


1>MyFrame.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual struct 

wxEventTable const * __thiscall wxSashWindow::GetEventTable(void)const " (?

GetEventTable@wxSashWindow@@MBEPBUwxEventTable@@XZ)


1>MyFrame.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual class 

wxEventHashTable & __thiscall wxSashWindow::GetEventHashTable(void)const " (?

GetEventHashTable@wxSashWindow@@MBEAAVwxEventHashTable@@XZ)


1>MyFrame.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "int const wxEVT_SASH_DRAGGED" (?

wxEVT_SASH_DRAGGED@@3HB)
```

this is my code:

```
  //Frame.h
    #ifndef __MAIN_FRAME__
    #define __MAIN_FRAME__
    #include "wx/frame.h"
    #include <wx/laywin.h>
    //#include <wx/sashwin.h>
    class MyFrame : public wxFrame
    {
    public:
        MyFrame();
        MyFrame( wxWindow* parent, wxWindowID id, const wxString& title, const wxPoint& pos = wxDefaultPosition, const wxSize& size = wxDefaultSize, long style = wxDEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE, const wxString& name = _T( "Frame" ));
        ~MyFrame();
        void OnDrag(wxSashEvent &event);
        void OnSize(wxSizeEvent& event);
    private:
        wxLayoutAlgorithm _layout;
        wxSashLayoutWindow *window;
        wxSize siz;
        DECLARE_DYNAMIC_CLASS( MyFrame )
        DECLARE_EVENT_TABLE()
    };

    #endif
    //Frame.cpp
    enum
    {
        ID_BTN_FIRST = 100,
        SASHID
    };
    IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC_CLASS( MyFrame, wxFrame )
    BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(MyFrame ,wxFrame)
    EVT_SASH_DRAGGED(SASHID ,MyFrame::OnDrag)
    EVT_SIZE(MyFrame::OnSize)
    END_EVENT_TABLE()
    MyFrame::MyFrame()
    {
    }

    MyFrame::~MyFrame()
    {
    }

    MyFrame::MyFrame(wxWindow *parent, wxWindowID id, const wxString &title, const wxPoint &pos, const wxSize &size , long style , const wxString &name )
    :wxFrame( parent, id, title, pos, size, style, name )
    {

        siz = wxGetDisplaySize();
        window  = new wxSashLayoutWindow();
        window->Create(this ,SASHID );
        window->SetDefaultSize(wxSize(200 ,siz.GetHeight()));
        window->SetOrientation(wxLAYOUT_VERTICAL);
        window->SetAlignment(wxLAYOUT_LEFT);
        window->SetBackgroundColour(this->GetBackgroundColour());
        window->SetSashVisible(wxSASH_RIGHT, true);
        wxPanel *panel = new wxPanel(this); 
        MWTreeCtrl *tree = new MWTreeCtrl(window);


        _layout.LayoutFrame(this ,panel);

    }
    void MyFrame::OnDrag(wxSashEvent &event)
    {
        window->SetDefaultSize(wxSize(event.GetDragRect().width, siz.GetHeight()));
        _layout.LayoutFrame(this ,panel);

    }
    void MyFrame::OnSize(wxSizeEvent& event)
    {
        _layout.LayoutFrame(this ,panel);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you linking with the advanced library?

http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/page_libs.html#page_libs_wxadv

Comment: And also the "Library" section of [wxSashWindow documentation](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_sash_window.html)